# How to make progress dialog for database copying?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a game with a sqlite database, 10MB large. So, after installing the game, and upon first game start the database is being copied to internal memory and that takes a while, maybe 30 seconds, with black screen. This is pretty bad cause a user can think that the game froze. I was thinking, is there a way to show something like on the image below, saying "Copying DB in progress" or something, once the main menu opens? And how can I do that?

I'm copying my db from Assets folder using this code:

```
TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)"....says there...and copying takes at least 15-20 seconds. Is there a way to use progress dialog?

Comment: Also, if I use progress dialog, is there a way for it to stop it by itself once it's done, or do I need to give it something like 15-20 seconds and after that to shut it down?

Comment: What you could do with an `AsyncTask` would be : before starting, open dialog, do your stuff in background while sending updates to the progressbar, and once it's finished close the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bar can be used with asyncTask. As you know the **UI thread** should be spared
 from heavy operation that can affect the responsiveness of the UI. Now this is when you
 use worker threads.

It can be very easy to use progressBar with async task... But since u didnt want asyncTask here is one example.

```
  btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);//the button that starts your function
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
             new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        //reset progress bar status
        progressBarStatus = 0;

        //reset filesize
        fileSize = 0;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

              // process some tasks
              progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

              // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              // Update the progress bar
              progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                }
              });
            }

            // ok, file is downloaded,
            if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // close the progress bar dialog
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
          }
           }).start();

           }

            });

    }

// file download simulator... a really simple
public int doSomeTasks() {

    while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

        fileSize++;

        if (fileSize == 100000) {
            return 10;
        } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
            return 20;
        } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
            return 30;
        }
        // ...add your own

    }

    return 100;

}
```

Click here for the [sourcecode.](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Android-ProgressBar-Example.zip)

**EDIT:**

Check this tutorial .[Click here.](http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/)

Comment: Do I have to use the button? I really don't need it. Can I just put this in onCreate method of my main activity?

Comment: I get bunch of error, I don't even know where to start telling you. I guess this code is something that works for you, but it does not for me.

Comment: check the edit.. and also the link above.. it has the source code. You can download and import it into your project.